# How to use a Media Image Attribute

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento-2.1, product-images, attribute-set

Magento 2.1.1

I added a product attribute media-image and I added it in the attribute set. I then can add images in my product and select one to play this role.

But how do I call this image in my phtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Here `desc_logo` is **attribute id**

```
<?php
                  $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);  
                    $attrImage = $_product->getData('desc_logo');   
                    if(isset($attrImage) && $attrImage != 'no_selection' ){
                        $productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'desc_logo' );
                        $productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                        ->init($product, 'desc_logo')
                        ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());?>
               <img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getTitle()) ?>" />
               <?php }
                  else{
                    //echo "No";
                  }
                  ?>
```

Comment: I could bet I tried that before and it did not work... well, now it does, thank you, even more for the record 11 minutes answering time.

Comment: I added a product attribute as drop down - now how do i display an image on product page? magento 2.1.1

Comment: Please explain it more

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in list.phtml. But it shows nothing.

My attribute name: **on_hover**

```
 $productId = $_product->getId();
 $_productat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);  
 $attrImage = $_productat->getData('on_hover');   
 if(isset($attrImage) && $attrImage != 'no_selection' ){
  $productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'on_hover' );
  $productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                            ->init($product, 'on_hover')
                            ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());?>
  <img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getTitle()) ?>" />
                   <?php }
                      else{
                    echo "No";
                      }
```

Thanks